On the homepage, why does it say Community bot modified x hours ago?
I was looking for questions to answer in https://askubuntu.com. At the bottom of the image, it says Community Bot 1 modified 3 hours ago. I think users want to see the latest activity of a question not including the Community user in most cases because it doesn't make very many edits that users care about most of the time. (Commonmark Migration, for example.) Can it not show the Community user's edits?
Edit: I understand why the feature exists. I now don't want it to be removed.


The most recent activity on that question is that it was bumped by the Community user.
There are posts which were bumped more than this one.
IIRC the various migrations and https rewrites did not cause bumping.

Why does it bump if is something unimportant? This is how you make a feature request, right?

You can have a look at the FAQ post: Who is the Community user? Or at various related posts on this meta.

As of current writing, it's unclear if this is a feature request, especially since the title asks for "why". You can [edit] and reword the title and the body to clarify what feature you are proposing, along with the reasoning.

@MetaAndrewT. The info about the [tag:feature-request] tag says "Proposals for new features on the Stack Exchange network, or requests for a change to an existing feature."
Anyways, the question Who is the Community user? answers mine (I didn't know the Community user could bump posts)

As it's currently written, this is not a duplicate as you clearly suggest to change the current behaviour which is indeed explained in the other question. If you don't want it changed, please edit and I'll close again.

Do you actually understand the feature you're asking to be removed? Usually these bumps happen to prod people to vote on answers so a question can be considered "answered" (or so we know the answers aren't great), but there are other reasons why Community will bump a post. Note that the Comminmark migration wasn't one of them; these edits were done with a special tool that doesn't bump the affected posts.

@Laurel Now I understand why the feature exists. I now don't want it to be removed.

@ShadowWizard I didn't know the Community user can bump posts

@ShadowWizard You can close it
